# VueJS reinstall dependencies

Tags: vuejs2

I've been developing with VueJS 2 for a couple of weeks now and tried to deploy for production, but ran into an issue. I wanted to test on a different system, so I deleted my node_modules folder and rebuilt my dependencies (npm install). However, when I npm run dev now, it doesn't work anymore. I didn't change anything in my package.json. My webpage gives me the following errors:

You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

```
(unknown) ReferenceError: _h is not defined
at Proxy.render (eval at (app.js:1596), :3:14658)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (eval at (app.js:606), :3096:22)
at VueComponent.eval (eval at (app.js:606), :2464:21)
at Watcher.get (eval at (app.js:606), :1663:27)
at new Watcher (eval at (app.js:606), :1655:12)
at VueComponent.Vue._mount (eval at (app.js:606), :2463:19)
at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at (app.js:606), :6104:15)
at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at (app.js:606), :8494:16)
at init (eval at (app.js:606), :2777:11)
at createComponent (eval at (app.js:606), :4120:9)
logError
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to coming from `vue-template-compiler`, which is described [here](https://github.com/vue-play/vue-play/issues/40) as well. The solution can be to downgrade vue to prior `2.1.5` since this is where the bug was introduced (also downgrade vue-template-compiler to same version).

I found one more reference [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4536) which points to [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/4b51ad048306367a6fb6fbee7445e086d855f31e) commit.

Comment: Ok I'll try. But I'm not using vue-template-compiler (it's not in my dependencies). Worked fine so far. Do I need it?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to downgrade my Vue. I change it to 2.1.8 in package.json, but later changed it back to 2.0.1. However, my Vue devtools keeps telling me I'm running 2.1.8. I removed all node modules and reinstalled! Where is it getting 2.1.8 from?

Comment: @Cake You may not be using it directly, but may be it is dependency of one of the package you are using, you can see all packages depending on `vue-template-compiler` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/vue-template-compiler).